# Search Guard Kibana clientcert authentication

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, client-certificates, mutual-authentication, kibana-5

I have installed Search Guard for Elasticsearch 5 and configured authentication only through client certificate with CN as username.

```
      clientcert_auth_domain:
        enabled: false
        order: 2
        http_authenticator:
          type: clientcert
          config:
            username_attribute: cn #optional, if omitted DN becomes username
          challenge: false
        authentication_backend:
          type: noop
```

Also I installed Search Guard plugin for Kibana.

How can I canfigure Search Guard for Kibana to use client certificates for users to log in? I see only option to use username password or LDAP in documentationas:
https://github.com/floragunncom/search-guard-docs/blob/master/kibana.md

But I would like to use client certificates as configured in Search Guard for Elasticsearch. I do not see any configuration options to enable clientcert authentication also for kibana users.

Still I have to log in through form where I should insert username and password.

Answer (score 3):

Kibana acts like a proxy for Elasticsearch, and by default discards most of the information contained in the original HTTP call, including the HTTP header fields containing your client certificate.

However, you can whitelist HTTP headers explicitly in kibana.yml, so you could try to whitelist the `"X-Client-Cert"` header like:

```
elasticsearch.requestHeadersWhitelist: [ "authorization", "X-Client-Cert" ]
```

Disclaimer: I work for [floragunn / Search Guard](http://floragunn.com)